# Intuitive Rectangle Clustering of Text Document

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project that needs to locate specific blocks of text on an image of a document. I have already located bounding boxes for all text, usually one per 'line' but occasionally, if the spacing is too wide, the granularity is per word. The best approach that I can think of is an intelligent clustering solution. Attached is an image as an example. Green rectangles are detected text, red rectangles are examples of a 'bad' cluster, and blue of a 'good' cluster.

These rectangles are stored in a list as `[top-left-x, top-left-y, width, height]`

The only assumptions that I can make about the regions of interest (good clusters) are that they:

- Will never be wider than 50% of an image
- Will always consist of 3 to 5 individual(green) rectangles
- There will always be two clusters of interest

I lack experience with clustering algorithms, and no other solution really comes to mind. Speed of computation is not a big issue, but precision is crucial. I am working on an alternative, template based solution but the more general solution is usually the superior one, where possible.

I attempted processing the list of rectangles in such a way that I could extrapolate a list of 'rows' or a list of 'columns' but as you can see there is a fair amount of variance for these. For example a rectangle could straddle two 'rows', and the same goes for columns.

Perhaps I could implement a rather greedy clustering function, then filter clusters by minimum variance in the x value of their centroids?

The question: Could someone with more mathematical/practical expertise recommend further approaches to solving this problem?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hct62.png)

Comment: Have you tried using [morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)? They let you easily remove text or select text by expanding black or white coverage.

Comment: I have used them in this project, but not for this specific task. If I were to aggressively cluster as mentioned towards the end of my question, then that could be an option. Will likely prototype that approach tomorrow, but am hoping for more approaches. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand much from your explanation, but wouldn't it suffice to calculate the ratio of total area covered by green boxes to the total area of their enclosing blue or red box? The closer to 1, the better.

Comment: That is a pretty good suggestion, I'll have to look through some samples to see if it holds. I will try it out. Thank you!